# with ELK find most frequent error strings in log

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

Using logstash, elasticsearch and kibana I'd like to find the most frequently occurring error strings in some logs.  It's quite easy to find the most frequently occurring words in the error messages, or the most frequently occurring checksum of the error strings, but I can't see how to monitor the error strings.

Comment: You may also be suffering if your strings are being analyzed, which will break them into words.  logstash provides a "raw" version (e.g. myField.raw) which is not analyzed.

Comment: Thanks Alain: If you use a custom name for the index - that is not "logstash-*" then the not analysed raw version is not generated.  Rather unexpected behaviour which caught me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily perform this task using Kibana 4 table visualization by selecting the terms aggregation over the error string field and using count to count the number of results per each error string.

You can read more about visualizations here:

"https://www.timroes.de/2015/02/07/kibana-4-tutorial-part-3-visualize/"

Comment: Thanks Tom:  I like the "uncommonly common" aggregation in the document you kindly linked to.